# Ionic serve suddenly stops working in ionic 6

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, terminal, angularfire2

I'm trying to serve my ionic app on my windows pc and each time I try to run "ionic serve", i get the response "mgdule is not defined" on the terminal. The annoying part is that it was working fine about thirty minutes earlier I closed the server with CTRL+C and took a break and when I wanted to continue, this started happening.

Comment: What happens if you use `ng serve` instead?

Comment: Did you install any new package via npm. In that case delete node modules folder and try ***npm install*** again

Comment: ng serve works but it doesn't give the ionic experience.

Answer (score 1):

Re-installing **ionic/cli** fixed the problem

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).